# Angular 2 - install on standalone computer

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm trying to install Angular 2 on standalone computer.
I tried to install the framework on a computer that connected to the network with the following steps:

1) download the [quick start from github](https://github.com/angular/quickstart).

2) cd to the quickstart-master directory.

3) use npm install.

4) use npm start.

the "Hello Angular" application is running successfully.

After I copied the quickstart folder to the standalone computer (which has node installed) I did the following steps:

1) cd to the quickstart directory.

2) used npm start.

This time when the chrome browser is opened I get "Loading AppComponent content here..." and **NOT** "Hello Angular".

How can I use Angular 2 on the standalone computer?

thanks a lot!

Edit:
The stack trace:

> SyntaxError "Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected identifier SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected identifier at eval (native) at ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:365:26) at
>   Zone.run(http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:125:43)
>   at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:760:57 at
>   ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:398:31)
>   Evaluating http://localhost:3000/systemjs-angular-loader.js Error
>   loading http://localhost:3000/systemjs-angular-loader.js Error loading
>   http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js as "./app/app.module" from
>   http://localhost:3000/main.js at new Error () at
>   Error.ZoneAwareError
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:917:33) at
>   addToError
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:122:82)
>   at linkSetFailed
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:695:21)
>   at
>   http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:495:9
>   at ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:365:26) at
>   Zone.run
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:125:43) at
>   http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:760:57 at
>   ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:398:31) at
>   Zone.runTask
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:165:47) at
>   drainMicroTaskQueue
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:593:35) at g
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js:8:10016)
>   at
>   http://localhost:3000/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js:8:10138
>   at MutationObserver.h
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js:8:14293)"

Comment: I guess you have to do **npm install** again, which will install all your dependencies mentioned in package.json.

Comment: Did you copy the `node_modules` as well ? If not, you'll have to `npm install` as @AmitChigadani suggested.

Comment: @YounesM I Copied the node_modules as well. And I cannot use npm install on standalone computer.

Comment: @AmitChigadani unfortunately That's not the solution.

Comment: Can you tell us what's the stack trace on the Dev Tools Console ? (F12 if you're using chrome)

Comment: Also, are the npm / node versions the same one both computers ?

Comment: @YounesM The npm version is the same but the node version is 6.9.5 on the standalone and 6.10.0 on the internet computer.